# Could it be possible to activate PNG upload in the WP media center for blogs?

Tags: feature-request, images, blog

I am sometimes (less than I want...) editing blog posts for Arqade and/or IT Security. I've been confronted with a problem regarding images. Whenever I try to upload a PNG file, it says my request has been denied for 'security reasons'.

Would it be possible to remove this?

The main reasons would be that

1. I don't see (really I'm trying) why PNG would be less secured than JPG
2. PNG format is better for computer generated images (less space)
3. It is actually possible to use PNG when linking a imgur.com PNG image

Or maybe there is a problem I am not aware of?